# SCIP and Branch and Price

Tags: c++, scip

I have a general question about SCIP. I need to use the SCIP as a Branch and Price framework for my problem, I code in c++ so I used the VRP example as a template. On some of the instances, the code stops at the  fractional solution and returns that as a optimal solution, I think something is wrong, do I have to set some parameters in order to tell  SCIP look for integer solution or I made a mistake, I believe it should not stop and instead branch on the fractional solution until it reaches the integer solution (without any other negative reduced cost column). I also solve the subproblem optimally! any commenets?!

Comment: Hi, could you please provide us with more details about your changes to the VRP example, in particular, to the pricer code? Besides, how far is your solution from being integral? Could you add some solution output of SCIP, that you obtain via [SCIPprintSol()](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/scip_8h.php#a3bd6c0f66c0179c77cf4c708ee2bef45)?

Comment: I changed the VRP code and adapted it for the non-metric version of the uncapaciated facility location problem, the major changes in the pricer code is related to pricing function where I have to find the minimum cost subset of facilities as an entering columns.

Comment: I also used a stabilization method in a way that the new duals in each iteration are the convex combination of the previous(iteration) and current dual variables. The rest of the code is the same with minor required changes. The variables in the master problem are all continious

Comment: I used the SCIP to solve the sub-problem optimally (finding the minimum negative reduced cost subset of facilities). output  Solution           :
  Solutions found  :          3 (3 improvements)
  First Solution   : +1.90000000000000e+01   (in run 1, after 1 nodes, 0.02 seconds, depth 79, found by <shiftandpropagate>)
  Primal Bound     : +0.00000000000000e+00   (in run 1, after 1 nodes, 0.02 seconds, depth 0, found by <relaxation>)
  Dual Bound       : +0.00000000000000e+00
  Gap              :       0.00 %
  Root Dual Bound  : +0.00000000000000e+00
  Root Iterations  :         16

Comment: stored the 3 best primal solutions in the original solution cadidate list
  2.3s|     1 |     0 |     5 |     - | 165k|   0 |   - |   8 |   2 |   8 |   2 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 4.000000e+00 | 4.000000e+00 |   0.00%
  2.3s|     1 |     0 |     5 |     - | 165k|   0 |   - |   8 |   2 |   8 |   2 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 4.000000e+00 | 4.000000e+00 |   0.00%

Comment: SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 2.33
Solving Nodes      : 1
Primal Bound       : +4.00000000000000e+00 (3 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +4.00000000000000e+00
Gap                : 0.00 %
objective value:                                    4
T_0_3                                             0.5  (obj:7)
T_0_1_3_5                                         0.5  (obj:1)
stored the 3 best primal solutions in the original solution cadidate list

Comment: T_0_3 = 0.5(obj:7) the value of this variable is half

Comment: T_0_1_3_5 = 0.5 (obj:1)the value of this variable is half

Comment: Do you specifically create those variables as `SCIP_VARTYPE_INTEGER` or `SCIP_VARTYPE_BINARY`?

Comment: If the variables in the master problem are all continuous, why should SCIP branch? Do you somehow enforce integrality?

Comment: In my model, I only have variables like tour-variables in VRP example. As you can see, these tour variables in the VRP are Continuous, if I make them Binary or Integer, then the master problem become an IP problem which is not correct, they should be fractional.

Comment: The only way to enforce the integrality in SCIP is through variables?

Comment: Perhaps, you should first define what you mean by integrality. Normally, this means that some variables need to have an integer value in every feasible solution. The natural way to handle this is to say that the variable is of integer type and let SCIP handle it. If you want to have integrality on these variables, I don't see how making them integer should be incorrect. But this is not the only way to handle integrality, you can also write a constraint handler, which checks every solution and can then enforce integrality either on variables or on some implicitly given decisions.

Comment: my understanding from the Branch and Price procedure is as follow: you first solve the Restricted Master Problem(RMP) which is a LP problem and get the duals, then you look for a negative reduced cost columns with respect to duals, if you find one then you add this column to the RMP and solve it again, but if there is not any negative reduced cost column you have to check if the solution to the RMP is integral or not, if it is integral then you are at the optimal , if not you have to choose a variable and branch!! I thought if you set the pricer correctly , SCIP will do this process!!

Comment: Maybe I have to manage the branching after I check for the negative reduce cost and not finding such a column, for example in the following code from pricer of VRP:

Comment: /* add tour variable */
   if ( SCIPisNegative(scip, reduced_cost) )
   {
      return add_tour_variable(scip, tour);
   }

Comment: if I do not find any reduced negative cost, I can check to see if the solution is integral and if it is not, I can bracnh on some variables, what do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define your variables to be continous and just add a pricer, SCIP will solve the master problem to optimality (i.e., solve the restricted master, add improving columns, solve the updated restricted master, and so on, until no more improving columns were found).

There is no reason for SCIP to check if the solution is integral, because you explicitly said that you don't mind whether the values of the variables are integral or not (by defining them to be continuous). On the other hand, if you define the variables to be of integral (or binary) type, SCIP will do exactly as I described before, but at the end check whether all integral variables have an integral value and branch if this is not the case.

However, you should note that all branching rules in SCIP do branching on variables, i.e., they take an integer variable with fractional value and split its domain; a binary variable would be fixed to 0 and 1 in the two child nodes. This is typically a bad idea for branch-and-price: first of all, it's quite unbalanced. You have a huge number of variables out of which only few will have value 1 in the end, most will be 0. Fixing a variable to 1 therefore has a high impact, while fixing it to 0 has almost no impact. But more importantly, you need to take the branching decision into account in your pricing problem. If you fixed a variable to 0, you have to keep the pricer from generating a copy of the forbidden column (which would probably improve the LP solution, because it was part of the former optimal solution). In order to to this, you might need to look for the 2nd (or later k)-best solution. Since you are solving the pricing problems as a MIP with SCIP, you might just add a constraint forbidding this solution (logicor (linear) for binary variables or bounddisjunction (not linear) for general integer variables).

I would recommend to implement your own branching rule, which takes into account that you are doing branch-and-price and branches in a way that is more balanced and does not harm your pricing too much. For an example, check out the Ryan&Foster branching rule, which is the standard for binary problems with a set-partitioning master structure. This rule is implemented in Binpacking as well as the Coloring example shipped with SCIP.

Please also check out the SCIP FAQ, where there is a whole section about branch-and-price which also covers the topic branching (in particular, how branching decisions can be stored and enforced by a constraint handler, which is something you need to do for Ryan&Foster branching): http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/FAQ.php

There were also a lot of questions about branch-and-price on the SCIP mailing list 
http://listserv.zib.de/mailman/listinfo/scip/. If you want to search it, you can use google and search for "site:listserv.zib.de scip search-string"

Finally, I would like to recommend to have a look at the GCG project: http://www.or.rwth-aachen.de/gcg/
It is an extension of SCIP to a generic branch-cut-and-price solver, i.e., you do not need to implement anything, you just put in an original formulation of your model, which is then  reformulated by a Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition and solved via branch-cut-and-price. You can supply the structure for the reformulation, pricing problems are solved as a MIP (as you do it also), and there are also different branching rules. GCG is also part of the SCIP optimization suite and can be easily built within the suite.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough information! I will work on this.